# Installing php-zmq extension on PHP 8.1 in a docker container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, zeromq

What is wrong with this Dockerfile?

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libzmq5

# Install the ZeroMQ extension
RUN pecl install zmq-beta

# Enable the ZeroMQ extension
RUN docker-php-ext-enable zmq
```

It seems that I cannot install php-zmq extension in PHP 8.1. Any tips on how can I proceed with the installation?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: I had the same issue with php:8.2-apache and stumpled over https://github.com/zeromq/php-zmq/issues/220 
mopsyd commented on Oct 1, 2021 a solution which worked for me. I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

git clone
https://github.com/zeromq/php-zmq

or download zip archive from repo

```
RUN apt-get install -y libzmq5 libzmq5-dev gcc unzip && \
    unzip php-zmq-master.zip && cd php-zmq-master && phpize && ./configure && \
    make && make install && docker-php-ext-enable zmq
```